# Bootstrap Datepicker not working in Umbraco backoffice

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, umbraco

Using `Umbraco 7` - odd issue. When either editing or creating a content (any content, doesn't matter the type), in the backoffice, if I go to the default `Properties` tab, the datepicker isn't working, it's just blank. The datepicker does not display if I click inside the textbox or on the gray box where the icon is supposed to be. If I refresh `F5`, the datepicker is there.

**No errors in console. Script files are in the header and can be accessed.**

[image]

---

**AFTER REFRESH**

[image]

Comment: Same in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar (but subtly different problem) with a document type that contains a "Date Picker with time" field.

In the content section of the back office, I view a previously saved document.

[image: before hitting F5]

Note that I do see the picker (unlike the original post) but that the value is blank.
Then, I hit F5.

[image: after hitting F5]

I now see the previously saved value that I knew was saved in the database for that field.

Surely a bug with the back office??

Comment: For whatever reason my issue corrected itself - don't know how or why. If you find an answer please post it.